# Japanese Kakasi Dictionary Has Some Weird Letters

Tags: dictionary, letters

I downloaded the source package of kakasi from: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/kakasi

```
plee@sos:~/Japanese/kakasi$ l
total 0
plee@sos:~/Japanese/kakasi$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kakasi/kakasi_2.3.5~pre1+cvs20071101.orig.tar.gz
--2012-10-08 11:01:00--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kakasi/kakasi_2.3.5~pre1+cvs20071101.orig.tar.gz
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com... 91.189.92.183, 91.189.92.184, 91.189.92.188, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com|91.189.92.183|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1329263 (1.3M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: 'kakasi_2.3.5~pre1+cvs20071101.orig.tar.gz'

100%[======================================================================================================================================================================>] 1,329,263    705K/s   in 1.8s    

2012-10-08 11:01:27 (705 KB/s) - 'kakasi_2.3.5~pre1+cvs20071101.orig.tar.gz' saved [1329263/1329263]
```

Then I uncompressed it:

```
plee@sos:~/Japanese/kakasi$ tar zxvf kakasi_2.3.5~pre1+cvs20071101.orig.tar.gz 
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/maintMakefile
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/INSTALL-ja
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/ONEWS
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/kakasi.spec.in
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/a2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/k2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/jj2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/itaiji.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/getopt1.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/getopt.h
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/dict.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/kakasi.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/kk2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/mkkanwa.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/atoc-conv.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/conv-util.h
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/78_83.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/conv-util.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/level.h
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/rdic-conv.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/ee2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/Makefile.am
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/Makefile.in
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/g2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/j2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/hh2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/kakasi.h
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/wx2-conv.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/level.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/kanjiio.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/src/getopt.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/config.guess
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/config.rpath
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/INSTALL
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/configure.in
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/AUTHORS
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/config.sub
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/NEWS
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/configure
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/tests/
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/tests/kakasi-6
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/tests/kakasi-5
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/tests/env.sh
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/tests/kakasi-2
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/tests/kakasi-1
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/tests/kakasi-7
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/tests/kakasi-4
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/tests/Makefile.am
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/tests/Makefile.in
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/tests/kakasi-3
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/ltmain.sh
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/THANKS
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/man/
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/man/kakasi.1.ja
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/man/kakasi.cat
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/man/kakasi.1
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/man/kakasi.cat.ja
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/man/Makefile.am
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/man/Makefile.in
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/aclocal.m4
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/kakasi-config.in
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/kakasi.spec
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/install-sh
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/missing
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/COPYING
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/README
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/kakasidict
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/README-ja
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/README.BeOS
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/README.lib
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/JISYO
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/CVS/
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/CVS/Repository
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/CVS/Entries
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/CVS/Root
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/README.wakati
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/README.level
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/ChangeLog.lib
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/doc/README.OS2
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/itaijidict
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/Makefile.am
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/TODO
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/kakasi.def
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libee2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libkanjiio.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libkakasi.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libg2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libhh2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libjj2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libdict.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/lib78_83.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libj2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/liba2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libkakasi.h
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libkk2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libk2.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/Makefile.am
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/Makefile.in
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/libitaiji.c
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/lib/makefile.msc.in
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/Makefile.in
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/magic-kakasi
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/ChangeLog
kakasi-2.3.5pre1/config.h.in
plee@sos:~/Japanese/kakasi$ l
total 1304
drwxr-xr-x 7 plee plee    4096 2010-03-21 19:36 kakasi-2.3.5pre1
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee 1329263 2010-05-09 09:06 kakasi_2.3.5~pre1+cvs20071101.orig.tar.gz
plee@sos:~/Japanese/kakasi$ cd kakasi-2.3.5pre1/
plee@sos:~/Japanese/kakasi/kakasi-2.3.5pre1$ l
total 3520
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee  365083 2010-03-21 19:35 aclocal.m4
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee     356 2001-04-12 02:36 AUTHORS
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee   19779 2007-11-01 00:00 ChangeLog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 plee plee   44959 2010-03-21 19:35 config.guess
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    2131 2010-03-21 19:35 config.h.in
-rwxr-xr-x 1 plee plee   14987 2004-03-01 23:01 config.rpath
-rwxr-xr-x 1 plee plee   34597 2010-03-21 19:35 config.sub
-rwxr-xr-x 1 plee plee  417371 2010-03-21 19:35 configure
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    2461 2004-09-30 23:03 configure.in
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee   35147 2010-03-21 19:35 COPYING
drwxr-xr-x 3 plee plee    4096 2010-03-21 19:35 doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee   15578 2010-03-21 19:35 INSTALL
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    9618 2000-03-03 22:37 INSTALL-ja
-rwxr-xr-x 1 plee plee   13663 2010-03-21 19:35 install-sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    2820 2000-03-03 22:37 itaijidict
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    1058 2000-12-27 01:15 kakasi-config.in
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee 2237449 2002-10-02 00:32 kakasidict
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    2789 2010-03-21 19:36 kakasi.spec
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    2789 2001-04-12 23:53 kakasi.spec.in
drwxr-xr-x 2 plee plee    4096 2010-03-21 19:36 lib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 plee plee  243455 2010-03-21 19:35 ltmain.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee     113 2003-03-12 06:46 magic-kakasi
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    1632 2001-01-04 09:14 maintMakefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee     811 2004-03-01 23:01 Makefile.am
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee   27109 2010-03-21 19:35 Makefile.in
drwxr-xr-x 2 plee plee    4096 2010-03-21 19:36 man
-rwxr-xr-x 1 plee plee   11419 2010-03-21 19:35 missing
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    3038 2004-07-26 22:57 NEWS
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    5632 2000-03-03 22:37 ONEWS
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    1727 2000-04-26 20:16 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee    1505 2000-04-26 20:16 README-ja
drwxr-xr-x 2 plee plee    4096 2010-03-21 19:36 src
drwxr-xr-x 2 plee plee    4096 2010-03-21 19:36 tests
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee     783 2006-09-21 02:30 THANKS
-rw-r--r-- 1 plee plee     441 2001-04-13 03:02 TODO
```

I found the encoding is wrong, so I used `iconv` to convert:

```
plee@sos:~/Japanese/kakasi/kakasi-2.3.5pre1$ vim kakasidict 
plee@sos:~/Japanese/kakasi/kakasi-2.3.5pre1$ iconv -f "EUC-JP" -t "UTF8" kakasidict > kakasidict.UTF8
plee@sos:~/Japanese/kakasi/kakasi-2.3.5pre1$ vim kakasidict.UTF8
```

Now the file seems okay, but there are weird entries whose last kana is a letter:

```
173 きづk 気付k
174 つk 付
368 いk 行
653 おりr 下り
```

What happened?

Comment: It seems these are some kind of special characters in the dictionary entries.  So I just want to find the rules of appending the new entries.  However, I googled a lot without luck.  I found several Japanese blog webpages, but difficult to read.  There must be an official website, telling us how they assemble the Kakasi dictionary, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a special syntax to match several forms of the same verb.
For instance, `いk` will match `いく` (iku) `いけない` (ikenai) `いかせる` (ikaseru) `いきたい` (ikitai) ...
It is not just with `k`, but with all verb prefixes, see for instance the line `たべt 食べ`, and potentially with all these letters: w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,z,b,n,m.

I have no reference for this, but after inspecting the file I am pretty sure it works this way.
*I maintain the Java version of Kakasi at https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/kakasi-java and I know that documentation for Kakasi is very scarce.*

Comment: Hmmm, thanks.  I know some basic grammars  of Japanese.  I just wanted to get all rules of the letters in the dictionary: `k, m, i, r, t` and maybe more? Can you show me the code that processes this letter expanding?  My project requires me to list the pronunciation of all words, so I think I need to expand to get all forms of the verbs

Comment: So I still did not quite get it. Can you show me which code in your kakasi-java is for the expanding? If `食べた` and `食べて` match `たべt 食べ`, then which will match `食べる`? Maybe there should also have an entry like this `たべr 食べ`?